# Delete duplicates but keep depending on hour difference

Tags: r

I would like to delete duplicates of customers who have been to a certain website more than once on the same day, but keep those that went more than 3 hours apart. For instance, there should just be one observation for John on the 2022-12-24 but there should be 2 observations for Abbie on  2022-12-18.

Is it possible to automatically do this with R given the current data structure, or do I have to divide between day, month, year, hour, minute, second and then manually delete them?

My dataset looks as follows:

```
structure(list(Name = c("John", "John", "John", "John", "John", 
"James", "James", "Sandra", "Abbie", "Abbie", "Abbie", "Abbie", 
"Abbie", "Abbie", "Abbie", "Michael", "Michael", "Michael", "David", 
"David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", 
"David", "David", "Edmund", "Charles", "Charles", "Nancy", "Emma", 
"Stephanie", "Stephanie", "Stephanie"), Date = structure(c(1640417400, 
1640331540, 1640331180, 1671783780, 1671523380, 1671090360, 1671003540, 
1667306100, 1670375640, 1670271360, 1669151640, 1671386520, 1671386400, 
1671385800, 1671359220, 1668642120, 1668275820, 1668095820, 1670055180, 
1669528080, 1669265700, 1668525360, 1667127420, 1667119740, 1667119380, 
1667115720, 1666106100, 1666106040, 1666198260, 1671629280, 1671095760, 
1672515000, 1673539500, 1670853060, 1670838660, 1669993680), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Count = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One idea using dplyr and lubridate.
I stored your data frame under `data` first.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
data2 <- 
  data |> 
  arrange(Name, Date) |> 
  mutate(Date2 = as.Date(Date)) |> 
  group_by(Name, Date2) |> 
  mutate(
    DateNext = lead(Date),
    Gap = int_length(interval(Date, DateNext)) / 60 / 60,
    maxGap = max(Gap, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

Now the question is just how you want to filter. If you want all user data for a user who visited a website more than three hours apart, you could just filter like this

```
data2 |> 
  group_by(Name)
  filter(maxGap >= 3)
```

If you want to narrow it down more just add columns to the `group_by`. On second thought, you may also want to adjust the `group_by` call when `data2` was built depending on what you want. However I hope this gives an idea how to do it at least